# how to use the grabcut algorithm with cuda8.0

Tags: cuda, npp

since the The 7_CUDALibraries/grabcutNPP and 7_CUDALibraries/imageSegmentationNPP samples have been removed. These samples used the NPP graphcut APIs, which have been deprecated in CUDA 7.5.

Then how to use the grabcut algorithm with the later version？

Comment: Have a look at what was done in OpenCV 3.1 . It had dependencies on the NPP graphcut APIs that needed to be replaced to work with CUDA 8

Comment: opencv added an  extra  definition  ' (CUDART_VERSION >= 8000)'  [opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/10896129b39655e19e4e7c529153cb5c2191a1db)  ,but it didn't solved this problem. @talonmies

Comment: OK so the answer is that they disabled it. I was wondering whether they replaced it with something else or not.

Answer (score 1):

The graphcut APIs in NPP were deprecated and removed during the CUDA 7 release cycle.

There is no direct replacement for them within CUDA (or OpenCV which used the NPP implementation).

[Answer assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get the question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag].